# Read host system's environment variables build time in Singularity

Tags: singularity-container

When I'm building a Singularity container I'd like to read environment variables from the host system in the `%post` section. I've been looking online for a way to achieve this, but to no avail. I'm starting to question if this is even possible at the moment, but I can't find any mentions of it being possible/impossible.

Example:

**Singularity definition file: recipe**

```
BootStrap: docker
From: continuumio/anaconda3

%runscript

%post
    echo $TEST_ENV_VARIABLE
```

**On the host system / OS**

```
export TEST_ENV_VARIABLE='foo'
sudo singularity build test.sif recipe
```

prints only a blank line when echoing TEST_ENV_VARIABLE.

If there is no way of reading host system's environment variables in the `%post` section, are there any other ways of passing arguments into the recipe that could be used build-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not currently possible, [though there is an open issue](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/issues/1676) for that functionality. I'm not personally a fan of dynamic build options as it makes it harder to guarantee reproducibility.

If you *do* want something more dynamic, you could use a template to create different definition files. A very simplistic example:

```
$ cat gen_def.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

my_def = """BootStrap: docker
From: continuumio/anaconda3

%post
    echo This is {0}
    echo This is {1}"""

print(my_def.format(*sys.argv[1:]))

$ ./gen_def.py one two > Singularity.custom

$ sudo singularity build test.sif Singularity.custom
```